# Why is the ##. operator needed in js_of_ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

Not sure why all those operators are needed. What's the rationale? Why is not the regular OCaml object syntax enough?

```
obj##.m
obj##.m := e
obj##m
```

Documentation here: http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/3.6.0/manual/ppx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml objects do not have properties. If you write `obj#m`, you are calling method `m` on object `obj`. If you write `obj#m := e`, you are again calling method `m` on object `obj` and it returns a value of type `'e ref`, which is then passed to operator `(:=)`.

Hence operator `##.`, which is just syntactic sugar for calling `Js.Unsafe.get`, respectively `Js.Unsafe.set`. (Similarly, `obj##m x y` is syntactic sugar for `Js.Unsafe.meth_call obj "m" [|x; y|]`.)

Rather than modifying the OCaml compiler in depth to actually map Javascript objects to OCaml ones and correctly recognize getters/setters, JSOO is a thin layer that depends on OCaml objects only for typing Javascript ones and ignores them entirely for execution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create a module or object as a base class that wraps around js_of_ocaml objects instead? To get rid of the heave syntax. Or maybe just alias `Js.Unsafe.get` to `get` locally?

Comment: The syntactic sugar is only there to ensure that expressions are correctly typed. If you do not care about typing you can indeed directly call `Js.Unsafe.get` or whatever alias you choose.

Comment: OK, but if it also checks the type it's not just a syntactic sugar...?

Comment: It is just syntactic sugar, but the generated OCaml code contains a lot of type casts `e : t`. The compiler is thus forced to check the types.

Comment: Hm, there's no manual page that extends the syntax, to demonstrate how it works? Like a "before and after" comparison.

Comment: There are some comparisons in the comments of the source file: https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml/blob/a8a41bc57f130e853a7398a2d4af1a885e2c1b7b/ppx/ppx_js/lib_internal/ppx_js_internal.ml#L322